# Performance of -endEditing vs conditionals in dismissing keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitextfield

When dismissing the keyboard in a background tap, I usually add a tap gesture recognizer to my root view and hook it up to a `dismissKeyboard:` `IBAction`, which can be implemented with either of the following methods:

```
// Method 1

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender
{
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

OR

```
// Method 2

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender
{
  if ([self.firstNameTextField isFirstResponder]) {
    [self.firstNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else if ([self.lastNameTextField isFirstResponder]) {
    [self.lastNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  // And so on for all UITextFields in the view
}
```

While the first method is convenient, I'm curious if it less desirable due to performance hits, Apple recommended best practices, or other reasons. The second method, while being quite verbose, only inspects the subviews you explicitly provide, and returns once it has found a text field to resign. For those reasons it continues to look like an appealing option.

Comment: Have you profiled this and found any performance issues? If not I wouldn't bother. If it really concerned you then you could lose the conditional and just call `resignFirstResponder` on any views that you believe might have first responder status, which will be a smaller subset than all `self.view`'s subviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a performance test tonight on the difference between these two methods of resigning the first responder.

For the first test, I allocated and initialized 4000 UITextFields and added them as subviews to the main view in a UIViewController. I then made one of the UITextFields a firstResponder, then took the current NSDate. I then called `[self.view endEditing:YES];` and took another current NSDate. I took the time interval between the start and end dates, and got a difference in seconds of: `0.000029`.

In the second test, I allocated one UITextField, set it as the first responder. I then performed the same NSDate calculation, but used an if statement to check and see if the UITextField was currently a firstResponder, and then called `-resignFirstResponder` if it was, indeed, the first responder. The time difference (in seconds) for this was: `0.000012`.

Both of these tests were ran on-device on an iPhone 5s.

So, what we're measuring here is how long the main thread is being blocked (which would cause a laggy feeling app). Still, it's pretty amazing to see that using `-resignFirstResponder` with a test to see if the textField is a first responder is only .000017 faster than just calling `-endEditing:YES` on the main view. What this shows though is that the performance difference between these two methods of relinquishing first responder status is really negligible.

I wonder what Apple is doing behind the scenes there?

Comment: Did you do it once, or multiple times and then average them? I would do it a few thousand times to see.

Comment: Can you take a deeper look at the call tree in instruments to get a vague idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about storing whatever becomes the first responder?  Then you just resign that on the dismiss?  You wouldn't need a conditional after that.

Comment: Interesting thought. Would you assign it in one of the `UITextField` delegate methods - maybe `textFieldDidBeginEditing`?

Comment: Yes that should be the right place and you would want to clear the value if it gets dismissed through textFieldDidEndEditing

Comment: but then the delegate needs to be called, if its not already, right? Time to consider there too